# Usage of Native SQL functions in ORMlite anotations

Tags: java, android, sql, ormlite

I am interesting in ORMlite usage in android application. But there is one problem. 
The first step is to annotate your class, but I need something like this:

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = "geometry", useGetSet = true)
String JSONgeometry;

@Formula (nativeSQL = "ShapeFromJSONText(JSONgeometry)")
public void set(String JSONgeometry){
    this.JSONgeometry = JSONgeometry;
}

@Formula (nativeSQL = "asJSONtext(geometry)")
public String get(){
    return JSONgeometry;
}
```

Is there any way to insert native SQl functions in annotations? Is there any way to use BasePersister for solving this tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific what functions `ShapeFromJSONText` and `asJSONtext` exactly do?

I feel from your approach that you want to save object in geometry field.

Create separate class in your model:

```
class Geometry {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    int id;

    @DatabaseField
    float field1;
    @DatabaseField
    float field2;
}
```

In your parrent class refer to it like this:

```
class Shape {
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    Geometry geometry;
}
```

Of course if you dont want to save object but just its JSON represenatation you can save it to the `String` field.

In case you want to use your SQL functions to change the saved object somehow you can do it in getter and setter too in Java.